# What is this device included in my Arduino parts Kit?

Tags: arduino, led, wiring

It was included with the light emitting LEDs so I assume it also gives off light? I understand the the shorter prong goes to negative/ground and the positive prong is longer, but this little thing has 4 prongs! How do I properly wire it?

[image: arduino part]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an RGB (color) LED. It contains 3 individual light emitting junctions, one each for red, green and blue colors. All 3 LED junctions share one common leg (probably that longest pin on the device) and have their other ends connected to one of the other 3 pins each.

Somewhere in the documentation you should find the pin-outs of the LED, or alternatively use an LED tester set at perhaps 5 to 10 mA to check each combination of the pins, in each direction, to identify the red, green and blue pins, and the common pin.

Such LEDs can be common anode or common cathode, i.e. the shared pin could be the anode or the cathode.

For your convenience, here are the pin-outs for two typical RGB LEDs, one [common anode](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/Components/LED/YSL-R596AR3G4B5C-C10.pdf) and one [common cathode](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/YSL-R596CR3G4B5C-C10.pdf), both sold by [SparkFun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10820):

[image: RGB LED pin-outs]

Pretty much any RGB LED such as the one shown in the question should follow one or the other of these pin-outs.

Comment: If you don't have a LED tester, you can use the diode-test function of a multimeter to test each combination of pins (even if it doesn't light the LED). If you don't have a multimeter, you should think about buying one new or on eBay.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Thanks, I should have mentioned that, since not everyone has an LED tester. Oh, and why "*new or on eBay*", I could buy one new *and* on eBay :-)

Comment: You could :-) Just don't be like me and become addicted to buying 2nd-hand Flukes at bargain prices on eBay :-(  ... (I have a 25, a 77-IV and an 87-III now)

Comment: Or you can use a coin cell battery or a nine volt battery WITH a 1~2k+ resistor to test it.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Which multimeter would you recommend? I was thinking this one: http://tinyurl.com/nnw2uyl In you guys' experience is this missing any core features I should look for? I cannot light the LED with this instrument correct? It just measures voltage and resistance?

Comment: @stormist the diode test mode should light up the led very very lightly. You should be able to see it.

Comment: @stormist: Audible continuity testing.